# Typescript: How to narrow down function return type based on function parameter value

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

I'm fairly new to typescript and can't figure out a way to properly narrow down the return type of a function based on an argument of that same function.

Consider the following code:

```
import exampleApiResource from './resources/example';
import exampleApiResource2 from './resources/example2';
import { ApiResources } from './typings';

const apiResources: ApiResources = {
  exampleResource: exampleApiResource,
  exampleResource2: exampleApiResource2,
};

export function useApiClient(resource: keyof ApiResources) {
  return apiResources[resource];
}

export default apiResources;

/** typings **/
export type ApiResources = {
  exampleResource: ExampleType;
  exampleResource2: ExampleType2;
};

export type ExampleType = {
  getExample: () => Promise<TestResource>;
};

export type ExampleType2 = {
  getExample2: () => Promise<TestResource>;
};
```

I want to expose the apiResources object through the useApiClient function. The exampleApiResource and exampleApiResource2 hold different properties, as you can see in the typings.

Typescript infers the useApiClient function to return the following types: ExampleType | ExampleType2

How would one narrow this down to a specific type, is this even possible?

--

**Use case:**

Expose an axios based API client through a function. The function accepts a parameter which will resolve to an object which contains functions to perform API related actions (E.G: getPosts(), updatePost() etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `useApiClient()` a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) whose type parameter `K` corresponds to the particular member(s) of `keyof ApiResources` passed in as `resource`:

```
export function useApiClient<K extends keyof ApiResources>(resource: K) {
  return apiResources[resource];
}
```

Now the return type of the function is `ApiResources[K]`, an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) corresponding to the type of the property value of type `ApiResources` at a key of type `K`.

---

You can verify that this will behave as desired when you call `useApiClient()` and return either `ExampleType` or `ExampleType2` depending on the input:

```
const ex = useApiClient("exampleResource"); // const ex: ExampleType
const ex2 = useApiClient("exampleResource2"); // const ex2: ExampleType2
```

You'll only get the union `ExampleType | ExampleType2` in cases where the input type is also a union:

```
const exUnion = useApiClient(
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? "exampleResource" : "exampleResource2"
);
// const exUnion: ExampleType | ExampleType2
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gEqYPYCuUSyA3gFDLIAeAXMiAQLYBG0A3OQL7kAmECADZwoKBHhBZkEanCYAHQRACC84LgyFiEegFFZCpagCe8iJ35CRYiVJlzFKtRq1IATHoOOTZt53LikmDIcM74REgY9Krq4doYyAC8ZJTSXkouETppDkoxmdoANKn2hhAF7vSljvlx7sVc-jLyeFDB-PAEgsGhsZpZGP4A9ABUI8hgpqAA5gljQ+TNrcGTZsi1-fFJKVTVGXXZ+rkQPuYl6eUHHshHZad+3E3ULW0Tpii33u-bFFTTEGBPkp6AAKACUSQAfMgAApQPBMYAYCAAHnQWAqEEhnEa5EWz2WbzWQJO7zcP1S-0BF2u4KhsPhiORaMwOAO2MeeLxS1eMAIIAQYGAEmQBGRMQAwoJgBBwCiANJpSAgXgJADWEGMeBg6zCm0ikJBon12XlEN+yFEYCIIBCetcmAA2saHQBdHHkIZDZB8gVCkVipzAKUyuWKmTK1XIDVanUbB0YQ0urL0M3Re0DR3y11cwJ2ajbQOS6WysAggBEe0uJvLYPYyC9yDzwRknmOpwCthb1HJySLahDpYrVcxblr9cbzbS1xJ9zxU5kAFUQMLbX3xQOS+AQQBZOBgAAWADooHAVQi6SjkAAGI8AVmQAH5kJWLpjy8h6K-jqPx57vQu1DLqubZ3N8AA+NwXHOQA)