# Typescript: How to narrow down function return type based on property of function parameter value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to narrow the return type of a function based on a discriminate property of a function parameter. I have found previous answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499231/typescript-how-to-narrow-down-function-return-type-based-on-function-parameter), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165536/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-input-parameter), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71224350/typescript-narrowing-a-type-union-from-function-return-types)) for narrowing the return type based on a parameter value, but they focus on the parameter being a string rather than an object, which is my use case.

The solution I have below works for using the function, but I get type errors within the function:

```ts
type CircleV1 = {
  type: "circle";
  colour: string;
};

type CircleV2 = {
  type: "circle";
  colour: string;
  sides: 1;
};

type SquareV1 = {
  type: "square";
  colour: string;
};

type SquareV2 = {
  type: "square";
  colour: string;
  sides: 4;
};

type ShapeV1 = CircleV1 | SquareV1;
type ShapeV2 = CircleV2 | SquareV2;

type ShapeType = (ShapeV1 | ShapeV2)["type"];

type GetTypeName<T extends ShapeV1> = T extends { type: infer TypeName }
  ? TypeName
  : never;

function convertToV2<TShape extends ShapeV1>(
  v1Shape: TShape
): Extract<ShapeV2, { type: GetTypeName<TShape> }> {
  switch (v1Shape.type) {
    case "circle":
      // Error: Type 'TShape & { sides: 1; }' is not assignable to type
      // 'Extract<CircleV2, { type: GetTypeName<TShape>; }> | 
      // Extract<SquareV2, { type: GetTypeName<TShape>; }>'.
      //   Type 'TShape & { sides: 1; }' is not assignable to type
      //   'Extract<CircleV2, { type: GetTypeName<TShape>; }>'.
      return {
        ...v1Shape,
        sides: 1,
      };
    case "square":
      return {
        ...v1Shape,
        sides: 4,
      };
  }
}

// This correctly infers that `shape` has type `CircleV2`
const shape = convertToV2({ type: "circle", colour: "red" });
```

[**Typescript Playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwglgJwMYBsIDUCMUC8UDeAUFFKJAFxQBESiqEVA3MVEgPYpsCuClAzsARwAdgHNmAX2aEy0eMjToATLgItZlGnTRMW7Tj36CR4lnzgATCH0qZJ02VADKARy4BDBBmx4iJDdR8bp4MzCT63LxQAkJi9oQy4NCuHl7Kqn6kSZpBqaF6HJFGsaYk5lY2UAAs8YmQzgAW7pBYqvL0rQA%20zsFpdnXJTS0qeO2KKt0pIcoOSY3NEAAqc3gAFE5D3lCTm8oAlADaVLJUALqz9QDiEMDLkABy7gC2EAA8i1AQAB7AEMIWfHmLUwAD5VB9vr9-oD8FkKFARAAzCAIKB3CCPF5QCQsAD8aKSmIgLEowggADcUdJEVxhEhgHA2MJWEzKQhbmxlO8NgtPj8-gCgd4QasWOTMDz4YtJcS9pQAKI-BDuemvGXKAA0BDhEEo11uhOeb2lmzBEjBmT4AHc4MAkA0oKtxTKAHSyPZqEjhdx8aBaBQMcgsL1QLzAHjMzIhkgu2POzYa4PR8rWWyJ6PYsJepA%20v25EJUIMZsMRz0ZqCxl3xhbp8spypVWshqQsHE4wjsYQCVjaDAjFnCNkc5SrWEBf30KhaiKGaheCxUbF7ZhAA)

Essentially I want a function that will migrate objects which from a discriminate union from one shape (schema) to a new one, with each object type requiring specific changes to match the new shape.

I've tried to do this in multiple ways, but always get stuck with narrowing the parameter inside the function body does not narrow the return type - within the function body the return type is not narrowed.

Comment: I suspect that this might be [a limitation of typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) currently

Answer (score 0):

It requires a little helper coding but it can be done.

```
type CircleV1 = {
  type: "circle";
  colour: string;
};

type CircleV2 = {
  type: "circle";
  colour: string;
  sides: 1;
};

type SquareV1 = {
  type: "square";
  colour: string;
};

type SquareV2 = {
  type: "square";
  colour: string;
  sides: 4;
};
type ShapeV1 = CircleV1 | SquareV1;
type ShapeV2 = CircleV2 | SquareV2;
type ShapeType = (ShapeV1 | ShapeV2)["type"];
type GetTypeName<T extends ShapeV1> = T extends { type: infer TypeName }
  ? TypeName
  : never;
// changes start here
type ConvertedToV2<TShape extends ShapeV1> = TShape["type"] extends "square" ? SquareV2 : 
  TShape["type"] extends "circle" ? CircleV2 : never; 
function convertToV2<T extends ShapeV1>(
  v1Shape: T
): ConvertedToV2<T> {
  function convertToV2_helper(
    v1Shape: ShapeV1
  ): ShapeV2 {
    switch (v1Shape.type) {
      case "circle":{
        v1Shape;
        return {
          ...v1Shape,
          sides: 1,
        };
      }
      case "square":
        return {
          ...v1Shape,
          sides: 4,
        };
    }
  }
  return convertToV2_helper(v1Shape) as ConvertedToV2<T>;
}
const circleV2 = convertToV2({ type: "circle", colour: "red" });
console.log(circleV2);
const squareV2 = convertToV2({ type: "square", colour: "blue" });
console.log(squareV2);
```

[Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6&ssl=57&ssc=23&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwglgJwMYBsIDUCMUC8UDeAUFFKJAFxQBESiqEVA3MVEgPYpsCuClAzsARwAdgHNmAX2aEy0eMjToATLgItZlGnTRMW7Tj36CR4lnzgATCH0qZJ02VADKARy4BDBBmx4iJDdR8bp4MzCT63LxQAkJi9oQy4NCuHl7Kqn6kSZpBqaF6HJFGsaYk5lY2UAAs8Y5OABbukFiq8vQtAD7OwWl2iZDOjc0qeG2KKl0pIcrMdUMQACpJqgAUDU3eUJPzygCUANpUslQAurPLAOIQwEuQAHLuALYQADwLUBAAHsAQwhZ8gw2WAAfKp3l8fn8AfgshQoCIAGYQBBQW4QB7PKASFgAflRSQxEBYlGEEAAbsjmAB6KmsRpiazRYCeYBQerIomOGBsYQUhA-CwLNjKN7rAYQ37-QHNTCgvALMUQQ7HE4fb6SgFUXIhKhQPFTNIqSgsBXzZVJU5qyFSrQKBh62DaDBGqCkvmMKCEBFcYRIYBwHmsHl8m7CpRvK0a6XeYErFhkzCKygLQi7Sjc3nIgVCkULUGZb2+-2B9iZ-k5pQAfXZKEgCDjJBICaT0awLDTrZUmTKAHc4MAkPUoCtm-MAHSyXZqRuNpDuPjQW30KjkbszqCjjZhdckLzAHjCac7xtj0+byAAGhYx+ilmstivN6k18b2J3c4XgR6DHIL5ne4PI8b1PMdzwgR8b1vCpKCqCCd2fGc3yxFgAIQQ9SxDCtqwgWtkRHRN5inedYGDLMIEFMM3mBSRCFLARWCddI8AwrMKxWGEAiXHQLyDAwoioLwLF1CRdmYOiOAgMdOFEFZaDtPYxJ5ejtUNVQWPLMN2NhCAcm-KgeIiQxqAAIxQLh7RExThD4CSpLYGSVOdUTCCAA)

The playground output:

```
[LOG]: {
  "type": "circle",
  "colour": "red",
  "sides": 1
} 
[LOG]: {
  "type": "square",
  "colour": "blue",
  "sides": 4
}
```

### Update:

Regarding checking the output of the help function to detect errors inside the function, the new `satisfies` keyword can detect that:

```
      case "circle":{
        // Using `satisfies` keyword introduced in TS 4.9 
        return {
          type: "square", // satisfies detects error
          colour: "red",
          sides: 4 // satisfies detects error
        } satisfies CircleV2;
      }
```

Also another way to map input types to output types is to use function overloads -

```
function convertToV2(shape: SquareV1): SquareV2;
function convertToV2(shape: CircleV1): CircleV2;
function convertToV2(shape: SquareV1|CircleV1): SquareV2|CircleV2 {
  switch (shape.type) {
    case "circle":
      return {
        ...shape,
        sides: 1,
      } satisfies CircleV2;
    case "square":
      return {
        ...shape,
        sides: 4,
      } satisfies ShapeV2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share this, I had't tried this approach. Unfortunately it allows non-typesafe code: if you return object of type SquareV2 from the first `case "circle":` there is no error, but the return of the wrapper function will be CircleV2. The `as ConvertedToV2<T>` is hiding this. I'm pretty sure now that writing this with type safety is impossible without the fix from the Issue linked above. I think the best option might be to use the types of the inner function you shared: less strict, but more "truthful", e.g. it's not going to tell you something is something it is not.

Comment: I am sorry but you are completely wrong.  I added runtime logging to the playground example to make that clear. It does not tell you something it is not. Perhaps you were confused by reusing the same variable name for the inner helper function?  That overrides the outer variable so there in no conflict.  (Did you even run a test?)

Comment: Thanks Craig, here's a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQJvGN) to show what I'm talking about. The issue is I'm looking for a type correctness that is not possible currently with Typescript: Typescript is unable to know, within the function body, that the return value should be narrowed because the parameter value has been narrowed.

Comment: Hi Gregor - Re: *Typescript is unable to know, within the function body, that the return value should be narrowed because the parameter value has been narrowed* - this is true, but as shown in the update, the new `satisfies` keyword can assist in getting it right.